# I need help decoding this message

Tags: cipher

I'm horribly stumped with this puzzle, anybody have an idea how to solve it?

```
'aea wldh te TlI dh wwno eor.s
```

(the TlI is capital T, lower case L, capital I)

It's part of a local Ready Player One scavenger hunt, inscribed on a red key. Should be a clue of what to do/where to go next?

[image]

Comment: *I'm putting this question on hold until proper attribution of its original source is provided.* — 
It looks like you're asking us to solve a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)**. At minimum you need to let us know where this came from; any additional context you can provide is usually a big help to solvers. Posts which use someone else's content without disclosing where it came from are generally deleted.

Comment: I added more info!

Comment: [Questions from on-going contests](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1674), competitions or tests are generally not accepted.